# Adafruit data shield RTC giving errors

Tags: arduino, i2c, adafruit, real-time-clock

I have an Adafruit data shield on an Arduino Mega. This is a new shield and battery. The battery has 3V. The RTC is a `PCF8523`. Using the example code I get this:

```
RTC is NOT running!

2165/165/165 (Monday) 165:165:85

 since midnight 1/1/1970 = 2087831889s = 24164d

 now + 7d + 12h + 30m + 6s: 2036/3/7 5:48:15


2165/165/165 (Monday) 165:165:85

 since midnight 1/1/1970 = 2087831889s = 24164d

 now + 7d + 12h + 30m + 6s: 2036/3/7 5:48:15


2165/165/165 (Monday) 165:165:85

 since midnight 1/1/1970 = 2087831889s = 24164d

 now + 7d + 12h + 30m + 6s: 2036/3/7 5:48:15
```

I tried running the [I2C scanner](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/)

I get this result:

```
I2C Scanner

Scanning...

Unknown error at address 0x01

Unknown error at address 0x02

Unknown error at address 0x03
.
.
.

Unknown error at address 0x7C

Unknown error at address 0x7D

Unknown error at address 0x7E

No I2C devices found
```

All the pins line up and are plugged in. I had a `BME280` temp, pressure and humidity sensor installed on the shield and I thought it was bad. After removing it, I still get the same errors. I haven't hooked up the `BME280` to another board yet to test it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a link to the hardware you are using and the *example code*.

Comment: [https://www.adafruit.com/product/1141]   [https://www.adafruit.com/product/2651]  [https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mega-2560-r3]      For the program, it's the test one that is mentioned with the board at [https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-data-logger-shield/using-the-real-time-clock]

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a new Mega board, data shield and pressure sensor. After doing some swapping around, I found that the I2C port on the Mega was bad. Everything works good on the new Mega board. The old Mega works except for that port.